# Converting a long number string into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So, let's say I have a string composed a very large number, say "123456789101112131415" for example. How do I convert that string into an array with those values in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite Easily Done:

```
"123456789101112131415".split("")
```

Comment: God, I'm way too dense. Thanks!

Comment: make sure you close the question, by choosing the best answer that helped you.